# Delete and recreate a Clash of Clans account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I accidentally left a clan after receiving troops, and now all of the clan members won't let me re-join and they are saying on global chat: "Don't let Corry join ur clan she is a hopper and she was only in our clan for a total of three seconds!"

So I'm not too popular at the moment and I want to delete and recreate a new account. I've tried to uninstall then reinstall but it's not working. Any ideas? If it helps I didn't bind my account.